# Use of variable in form submit confirm message

Tags: html, razor

I currently have the following code, intended to check with the user if they're sure they want to publish all of the events in a month:

```
@{
var message = "This publish all events in" + MVC.Events.PublishMonthParams.month.ToString();
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Events.PublishMonth(), FormMethod.Post, new { id = "publish-month" onsubmit = "return confirm('Are you sure?')" }))
{
@Html.Hidden(MVC.Events.PublishMonthParams.month, DateTime.Now, new { id = "month" })
@Html.SubmitButton(Strings.PublishAll)
}
```

But I would like to be able to display my "message" variable in place of the string "Are you sure?". However, I'm struggling to get the cshtml to recognise the variable. I've tried things like:

```
onsubmit = "return confirm(message)"
onsubmit = "return confirm('message')"
onsubmit = "return confirm(@message)"
```

but with no luck. Any advice on the best way to do this?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server-side code and client-side code.  Read the generated source.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually asking how to concatenate your `message` variable into the `"return ..."` string literal.
You can do that with regular server-side string concatenation.

However, this will create an XSS hole if the message has a quote.
You should call `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()` to escape special characters in the message.